# Can't Access x:Name of the list from the code behind in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

**I don't know why I can't access the x:Name of the list in xaml file from the code behind any help plz?**

I'm new to Xamarin and Im trying to build a basic project ,I tried to google some solutions but I found that my code is correct so I don't what to do now .

**here the xml file Posts.Xaml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="FavPosts.Posts">
    
        <ListView x:Name="listview" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                     Padding="5">
                            <Label  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Button Text="Favorite"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    
    </ContentPage>
```

and the **code behind** is Posts.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace FavPosts
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Posts : ContentPage
    {
        public Posts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class Post
        {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public string Details { get; set; }
        }


        List<Post> Posty = new List<Post> { 
            new Post { Status="f1", Details="D1" },
            new Post { Status="f2", Details="D2"}
            };


        listview.ItemsSource = Posty;
            
    }
}
```

and here are the errors
[image: and here are the errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place class Post outside from Posts!
To create List "automatically" you should place it in Constructor. But your main issue ist that class Post need to be outside

```
namespace FavPosts
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Posts : ContentPage
    {
        public Posts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Post> Posty = new List<Post> { 
               new Post { Status="f1", Details="D1" },
               new Post { Status="f2", Details="D2"}
            };


            listview.ItemsSource = Posty;
        }
     


        
            
    }
    public class Post
    {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public string Details { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! but please can u tell me why listview. Itemsources should be in the constructor?

Comment: Constructor is called every time Posts class created. In this case it will automatically create your list with post and populate your listview

Answer (score 1):

the statement "listview.ItemsSource=Posty1;" has a wrong location. it should be in a method.

```
public Posts() {
    InitializeComponent();
    listview.ItemsSource=Posty1;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot bro! but can u tell me plz why itemssource should be in a method?