# Xamarin Forms not recognising x:name"lvwPrice"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've been breaking my head on this for a while now and i can't seem to figure out why it keeps saying

> "lvwPrice does not exist in this current context"

My Xaml code:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="ProjectCrypto.Views.Overview">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="lvwOverview" RowHeight="100">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Coin}">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Key}" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                            <Label x:Name="lvwPrice" Grid.Column="2" Text="test" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text=">" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,16,0" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My xaml.cs code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ProjectCrypto.Repositories;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ProjectCrypto.Views
{
    public partial class Overview : ContentPage
    {
        public Overview()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();
        }
        private async void LoadData()
        {
            lvwOverview.ItemsSource = await CryptoRepository.GetCoins();

            var Coin = await CryptoRepository.GetCoins();

            foreach (var item in Coin)
            {
                lvwPrice.ItemsSource = await CryptoRepository.GetPrice(item.Key);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Is anyone able to help me out on why it doesnt want to detect `lvwPrice`?

Comment: x:Name="lvwPrice"  . Using x:Name in an ListView doesn't make sense, because you are presumably creating several instances of the view.

Comment: How would i change each listitem's 2nd label individually instead of using x:name?

Comment: use Data Binding.  Create a model that contains both Coin and Price and merge your data into a single list, or create a Property on Coin that will return the corresponding price from other list.

Comment: FYI for future readers, see [Can't Access x:Name of the list from the code behind in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64022720/cant-access-xname-of-the-list-from-the-code-behind-in-xamarin)… and many similar questions, google `site:stackoverflow.com xamarin forms x name not found listview`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to access templated elements by name and by whatever way you like, create a custom view that will serve You as a cell. And in the cell's code-behind you will be able to access everything by name. Your initial parent list will now look like:

```
     <ListView x:Name="lvwOverview" RowHeight="100">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Coin}">
              <DataTemplate>
                 <user:MyViewCell/>
              </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Your brand new cell will look like:

XAML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <ViewCell>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Key}" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Label x:Name="lvwPrice" Grid.Column="2" Text="test" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Text=">" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,16,0" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: Do you know of any link on how to do this or could you provide more detail on what to do? I understand like half what I need to do.

Comment: I managed to figure out what you mean, the only issue right now is i can't find how to link it. what do i have to type with xmlns?